# Visual Studio Not Throwing Errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Aloha guys, I have been using visual studio since 2005 and its a great piece of software but now I have the strangest case ever in history of programming.

I have upgraded my Windows to 7 and reinstalled my Visual Studio 10 recently and since then even though I explictly throw an exception in an application I dont get any kind of notification or dialog about the error.

It doesnt matter if I am in debugger mode or not, my application never crashes even when I purposly produce an exception in code.

Its the most weird behavior I have ever seen. Its impossible. Its like there is no error channel anymore.

**Its like the application jumps over the statements that produce errors and executes next ones but it doesnt crash.**

Is there some kind of setting for this in visual studio or somewhere else?

Does anybody have an idea what the f**** is wrong with my pc?

**Edit:**
What I mean is even when I have a simply console application with throw new Exception() inside my main the application doesnt crash.

Comment: Do you see the Exception in the output screen?

Comment: 1) Open Debug -> Exceptions and set checkboxes as you need. 2) Try to disable "Just My Code" in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General. 3) Ensure .pdb files is properly loaded in Debug -> Windows -> Modules.

Comment: Hi, I dont see exception in my ouput screen its like there is no error channel at all. I did try Debug -> Exceptions but still I cant make my application crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of problem happens, if your project is not properly built. Try to Rebuild the application. If it doesn't solve your problem, go and delete the bin folder manually and try to rebuild the project. Also, check the exception is raising or not after enabling exceptions in `Debug -> Exception -> CLRException`

Comment: I did all that but without success.

Comment: I think, better you re-install visual studio to fix this problem.

Comment: I did so and it works now. But all my settings are now gone. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Debug -> Exceptions -> and check that CLR Exceptions are entered.